# text-overflow as ellipsis not working

Tags: html, css

I have a table which is being dynamically populated from MySQL. The table has been applied with the following CSS

```
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I also have a defined width:

```
<td style="width: 100px">Some Stationers &amp; Printers , Yamunanagar</td>
```

I want that this to look like `Some Stationers &amp; Pr...`
I don't know what i am doing wrong here, any suggestions will be appreciated!

Browsers that this has been test on are Safari and Chrome, so just webkit!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Nope, text-overflow:ellipsis is supported in FF since 7.0.

Comment: @Boldewyn Yeah, but looks our friend is not using a modern browser... http://jsbin.com/udaquq/edit#javascript,html,live (working demo)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: You've added `display: block` to `td` in that demo..

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, not yet, but after adding it, i get some white-space on the left which i don't want.

Comment: @Namit, yeah... that's shitty. Try with `float:left;`

Comment: Yeah, it still left the white-space, however that i resolved by increasing the width of the `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *[Demo](http://jsbin.com/idoxum/2/edit)*

```
.table th,  
.table td {
  background:#eee;
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  float:left;        // added
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow) only applies to block elements (aka elements with `display: block`).

You will have to wrap the content in your `<td>`s to have the property take effect, like this:

```
<td>
  <div style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden">
    Some Stationers &amp; Printers , Yamunanagar
  </div>
</td>
```

(You could do this automatically with JS, if you can't touch the markup.)

Comment: Thanks, btw it is also possible to add the `display: block` style to the `td` so you don't need that wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

Hi u just add display:block in you td css

**css**

```
table th,
table td span{
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float:left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table><tr>
    <td><span>Some Stationers &amp; Printers , Yamunanagar</span></td></tr></table>
​
```

and [live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/PAJzK/24/)

http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/PAJzK/24/

Comment: `display: block` on `td` is a bad idea. The table functionality will be lost.

Comment: Also by using the `display:block` it leaves a lot of white space on the right, in the given demo too!

Comment: @thirtydot what you think about: `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @azad and if you rely on something like border-spacing?

Comment: now you can define to span tag in your td ex. http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/PAJzK/24/